# Venn Diagramm for amount of repeated terms between 4 groups

Tags: r

this is my df:

```
df <- data.frame(Group1=c("a","u","b","v","c","z","e","f","k","m","i"),
                 Group2=c("a","u","b","v","y","d","e","t","l","h","i"),
                 Group3=c("a","u","b","v","c","d","r","f","g","n","o"),
                 Group4=c("a","u","x","w","c","d","s","j","g","h","i"))
```

I would like to do a Venn diagram indicating:

- 2 elements are repeated in Group1, Group2, Group3 and Group 4.
- 2 elements are repeated in Group1, Group2, Group3.
- 1 element is repeated in Group1, Group3 and Group 4.
- 1 element is repeated in Group2, Group3 and Group 4.
- 1 element is repeated in Group1, Group2.
- 1 element is repeated in Group1, Group3.
- 1 element is repeated in Group3, Group4.
- 1 element is repeated in Group2, Group4.
- 1 element is repeated in Group1, Group2 and Group 4

I don't want to include the identity of the element that is repeated, I just want to state how many they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the `VennDiagram` package

```
library(VennDiagram)
venn.plot <- venn.diagram(x = as.list(df), filename = NULL )
grid.draw(venn.plot)
```

Hope it helps,
alex

Answer (score 0):

If we recast each column so they have the same levels:

```
levs<-unique(unlist(df))
df2 <- lapply(df, factor, levs)
```

We can then find the incidence matrix of each element in each column:

```
incid <- sapply(df2, table)
```

This is precisely the format that the `vennCounts` function from the `limma` package requires:

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("limma")
vennCounts(incid)
```

I guess you could copy the definition of the vennCounts function to save loading limma every time